# Android How to set TextView below RadioButton which have android:background property

Tags: android, radio-button

No one has responded yet. I've to complete this task. Someone help me please.

Earlier I had asked a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504416/how-to-rounded-radiobutton-in-andriod) but could not find any specific answer but I have found that problem. Now the problem I'm having is how to remove the `TextView` from this circle background and bring it down.

**Here is my xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEigene"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_flat_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/EigeneFragen"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_mine"
            android:drawablePadding="-1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Eigene"
            android:textSize="11sp" />
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Change the height to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

Change the height to "wrap_content" :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEigene"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_flat_selector"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/EigeneFragen"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_mine"
            android:drawablePadding="-1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Eigene"
            android:textSize="11sp" />
```

Comment: Read the question carefully that I've to bring this `TextView` below the circle which is a background.